# Mystifying For-Loop Error

Tags: c++, gcc, for-loop, ubuntu-10.10

I am using Ubuntu 10.10, Codeblocks IDE, and gcc compiler. I noticed the program I am writing was creating some odd output. Eventually I narrowed the issue down to a for-loop in the program. I was surprised to discover that the following basic for-loop didn't perform as expected.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
    cout << i << endl;
    }

return 0;

}
```

When I compile and run it, the output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Although one would expect the output should include zero. Very surprisingly, when I change the for loop to

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
    cout << i << endl;
    }

return 0;

}
```

I get the expected output of:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why 21 (and all numbers greater than 21) give me this false output, while 20 (and lower numbers) don't. If anyone has run into anything like this before, I'd sure appreciate hearing how he/she worked around it.

Comment: It works on ideone: http://www.ideone.com/jO8U0

Comment: Are you sure that the code you posted for the first snippet is identical to the code that you compiled?

Comment: Is this **the** actual code or a tailored one? By that I mean, you might be having `cout<<++i;` or stuff like that??

Comment: @Pawel Zubrycki Sure does! I hadn't heard of ideone, thanks for that. And at least I'm not missing something stupid.

Comment: For the first run, may be there is scroll bar in the output window which you didn't see :)?

Comment: 20 line console buffer?  Just a guess..

Comment: The code you have works as expected on my compiler setup. Are you sure this is the actual code? Is your console output bigger than 20 lines (hint: resize the console window)?

Comment: Run it from an honest terminal.

Comment: I thought it was the console buffer, but when I use a large number instead of 21, and scroll up, all the numbers are there except 0. And I am absolutely positive the code I pasted here is the code I ran.

Comment: I hit f9 in codeblocks, which builds and runs the console application.

Comment: @ergosys : endl flushes the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I'm really impressed.

Comment: @Martin, sure, but not what I was talking about.

Comment: @ergosys: Are you trying to suggest that when the buffer is full the content is dropped?

Comment: @Martin, Yes absolutely. A limited scroll-back buffer isn't unusual, but a 20 line one would be pretty lame.  Iostream buffers aren't what I was talking about if that is the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe the screen just scroll?

try to redirect the output to a text file

Comment: That worked! Not sure why the Codeblocks console isn't behaving, but it did output to a file correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seemed so weird that i run your first program and got what i would expect :

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

However, i notice that you use gcc as your compiler. This one is aimed towards c programming. Better use g++ as i did for this. It works fine here. (i'm actually surprised gcc compiles that :/)

Comment: I think he was referring to `gcc` as: Gnu Compiler Collection.

Comment: Yes, cnicutar, I am using Gnu Compiler Collection 4.4.5. Thanks for looking into it SpyrosP!